# How to print selected number of week in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have this code and I want to print the selected day of week (from server):

```
$daysOfWeek = array(
        "Lunedì" => 1,
        "Martedì" => 2,
        "Mercoledì" => 3,
        "Giovedì" => 4,
        "Venerdì" => 5,
        "Sabato" => 6,
        "Domenica" => 7,
    );
```

in my html code:

```
<select name="day" class="form-select">
   <?php

     foreach ($daysOfWeek as $dataDay) {
       echo "<option";
         if ($dataDay['numberDay'] == $day) { // DAY IS FROM A SERVER
             echo ' selected="selected"';
         }
         echo " value='" . $dataDay['numberDay'] . "'>" . $dataDay['day'] . "</option>";
     }
   ?>
</select>
```

basically i want to show the selected day in a option from server result

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to loop through a php list with foreach, and use both keys and values in your code, I recommend to use both "key" and "value" tags in creation of foreach.

```
<select name="day" class="form-select">
   <?php
        /*---- Create your foreach with keys and values in here ------*/
            foreach ($daysOfWeek as $key => $value) {

                /*---- Echo in here (with testing values) ----*/
                    echo "<option";
                        if ($value == $day) { // "$day" is numeric I assume
                            echo 'selected="selected"';
                        }
                    echo " value='" . $value . "'>" . $key . "</option>";
            }
   ?>
</select>
```